# Massive PDF Download with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pdf, download

I created a code to download PDFs massively with Selenium (Python) clicking in links. My code can access and click every link but it couldn't download these files.

My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

# Configurar las opciones de Chrome para la descarga de archivos PDF
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
'plugins.always_open_pdf_externally': True,
'download.default_directory': 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Archivos Laborales - Academicos/Packs de trabajos/PPC/PruebasWS',
'download.prompt_for_download': False,  # Cambiado a False para desactivar la ventana emergente de descarga
'download.directory_upgrade': True,
'plugins.plugins_disabled': ['Chrome PDF Viewer'],  # Deshabilitar el visor de PDF de Chrome
'safebrowsing.enabled': False  # Deshabilitar la verificación de seguridad })

# Inicialización del driver con las opciones configuradas
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)

for index, row in dfclaves.iterrows():
    val_0003 = row['clave1']
    val_00540503 = row['clave2']

    # Construir el nuevo enlace con los valores actuales
    new_link = f"http://extranet.zetagas.pe/guias-constancia/imprimir/{val_0003}/{val_00540503}/MAYOREO/2023"

    # Navegar a la URL utilizando el driver creado previamente
    driver.get(new_link)

    # Esperar un momento para asegurar la carga de la página
    time.sleep(3)  # Puedes ajustar este tiempo según sea necesario

# Cerrar el navegador al finalizar el bucle
driver.quit()
```

And the result is:

[image: Problem]

Can anyone help me please? I don't know what happens.

See ya. Thanks.